# Display woocommerce variable product description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

each variable product has an description field. This field doesn't show up on the single product page when a variation is selected. My question is how to achieve that this field will be displayed below the normal product description and also gets updated after I change the variation.

Best,
Patrick

[image]

Comment: Did you remove any actions?  I'm pretty sure it should show by default

Comment: What you want is to display **the product variation description** (but not the variable product one, as it's displayed like in any other product) … There is something wrong with your theme or with some customizations you have done, as this product variation description is displayed when the variation has been chosen from attributes values, when price appear…

Comment: I uploaded an image to clarify which field i mean. I tested it with a clean install and the twenty sixteen theme. This field is not showing up on the product detail page.